# How to add auto rotation in Next JS

Tags: next.js, metadata, meta-tags

```
<meta http-equiv="ScreenOrientation" content="autoRotate:disabled">
```

I want to add this tag in the Next JS metadata, but I don't have a proper way to add it. Please help me. I really appreciate any help you can provide.